# IIS publish 4.5.1 web application to application pool 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to run an website that I have hosted an IIS server using localhost, however, the MVC 5 project I have created uses .NET 4.5.1 and in IIS App pool I have selected v4.0 - Is this right?

The reason why I have asked is when I browse to the site, I get this error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I realise this is a reference problem but I have a feeling its to do with IIS and the app pool.

Any ideas?

**Please note I am deploying the site onto a different server**

Thanks

Comment: What server are you deploying to? IIS version and OS version?

Comment: Well the IIS app pool is 4.0 so I guess at least .NET4.0 is inistalled, OS is Win Server 2008 R2

Comment: Is `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` included in your deployment package?

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the answer which I have posted

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the answer,

Even though the Microsoft.Web.Infrastucture is referenced in the project (if not, get it using NuGet) you need to change `CopyLocal` to equal **true** when you click on the reference. Do this when deploying onto a server when Visual Studio isn't installed